# Save inkPicture in Database on VB.Net

Tags: database, vb.net

I need a lot of help. 
I want to record an ink picture in image to an access database.
 I already tried several ways but unfortunately
 I can not help someone because
 I am always trying and always error or binary long.
Please help me!
I Like finish my Work but not close procject unable to record the inkpicture within the database.
And Sorry my bad English

```
Dim tempPath As String = Path.GetTempPath
    Dim tempFile As String = (tempPath + serie_doc.Text + n_doc.Text & ".gif")
    Dim inkBox As Rectangle = InkPicture1.Ink.GetBoundingBox
    Dim point As Point = New Point(inkBox.Left, inkBox.Top)
    MessageBox.Show((point.X.ToString + (", " + point.Y.ToString)))
    Dim tempGraphics As Graphics = CreateGraphics()
    Dim inkRenderer As Microsoft.Ink.Renderer = New Renderer
    inkRenderer.InkSpaceToPixel(tempGraphics, point)
    MessageBox.Show((point.X.ToString + (", " + point.Y.ToString)))
    ' Clean up
    tempGraphics.Dispose()
    ' save the ink and background image to a temp file
    If (InkPicture1.Ink.Strokes.Count > 0) Then
        Dim bytes() As Byte = InkPicture1.Ink.Save(PersistenceFormat.Gif, CompressionMode.NoCompression)
        Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(bytes)
        Dim gif As Bitmap = New Bitmap(ms)
        Dim bmp = New Bitmap(InkPicture1.BackgroundImage)
        Dim g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
        g.DrawImage(gif, New Rectangle(point.X, point.Y, gif.Width, gif.Height))
        bmp.Save(tempFile, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif)
        Canhotos_AkfixTableAdapter.Gravar_mastik_canhoto(doc, serie_doc.Text, n_doc.Text, data.Text, n_cliente.Text, nome_cliente.Text, bmp, p_nome.Text, u_nome.Text, modo_pagamento, dias.Text, total.Text)
    End If
```

Best Reagrds

Comment: Could you post some code you have tried?  Errors you've gotten? I know in order to store images in a database you need to convert the image to a byte array and store it in a blob column.

Comment: I tried this code:

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here, I could have put the code.
The code I tried was this:

Comment: You should edit your question and add the code, not add it as an answer.  The code is not complete, you are missing an `End IF`.

Comment: I have to explain it badly, I want to write in the base of daos but it is in image, in this case in byte, only in the database when writing in normal byte, it says that it is a long binary, and I do not know what to do Can they help?

Answer (score 0):

I have a process that allows a user to upload a photo which I then scale and save in the database, I never save the image to disk it's all processwed in the memory of the computer.  It's not exactly the same as you're doing, but it should help you get started:

```
' Get the posted image file
Dim TheStream As Stream = file1.PostedFile.InputStream
Dim origimage As System.Drawing.Image
' get the image from the posted file stream
origimage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(TheStream)

Dim ms2 As New System.IO.MemoryStream
origimage = ScaleImage(origimage, 320, 200) 
origimage.Save(ms2, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
' convert to byte array
Dim MyPhoto() As Byte = ms2.GetBuffer ' The scaled image is now stored in memory
Session("ThePhoto") = MyPhoto ' put it into the session to retrieve later
ms2.Dispose()
```

It's at this point I have the image converted into a byte array, I save it to the session object because at this point the user has yet to save the data.  On another page I retrieve the image and same it to a `blog` column in the database.

Comment: Ok, what exactly is the issue? Can you post the errors you are getting?

Comment: My problem, is not error, is saving, but, in database at OLEObject Camp. I after save , i try open image, is not open and description is Binary is too Long.

Comment: Please post the code you use to retrieve the image.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "I try in access".  How do you try?  I see you have a call to `Canhotos_AkfixTableAdapter.Gravar_mastik_canhoto` in your code, is this where you save the image in an Access Database?

Comment: eu consigo, gravar tudo. só nao consigo gravar o inkpicture dentro da base de dados.
ja tentei gravar em bitmap e depois converter em byte(), mas após converter, ele corta metade da imagem,... acha que é possivel gravar em ficheiro isf, e depois caso preciso ver o conteudo, existe alguma forma de abrir?. Obrigado pela sua ajuda.